# Does the points of your neighborhood in hay day influence the neighborhood you fight against on next derby?

Tags: hay-day

My neighbor leader set minimum points to 290. That is even when the second place has far fewer points.

I observe that neighborhood with 20k - 25k points won almost as many first price as us.

Also when I am on more pathetic neighborhood, our competitors are not usually that smart.

I wonder. If we keep scoring high on derby will we face tougher derby opponents?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no. The points last for one derby only.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade. The reason your post was edited was likely due to the severe content issue. The content removed was effectively comments, and had no impact on the answer. For this reason, such content is not meant for answers, and will either be removed, or get the entire question flagged and consequently deleted.